# How to change secondary stylesheet with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have my base.css and a red.css on my site.

I like do change red.css for blue.css when i press some button, without lost base.css how to do this? i have tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if($.cookie("css")) {
     $("link").attr("href",$.cookie("css"));
  }
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#troca_faccao").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find("#painel_faccao").slideDown('fast').show(); //Drop down the subnav on click  
        $(this).hover(function() {
        }, function(){  
            $(this).parent().find("#painel_faccao").slideUp('slow'); //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up  
            });
        })
    $("#painel_faccao li a").click(function() { 
        $("link").attr("href",$(this).attr('rel'));
        $.cookie("css",$(this).attr('rel'), {expires: 365, path: '/'});
     return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

and div:

```
                        <div id="painel_faccao" style="display: none">
                        <p>A Escolha é Sua!</p>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="horda"><a href="#" rel="horde.css">HORDA</a></li> 
                            <li class="alianca"><a href="#" rel="aliance.css">ALIANÇA</a></li> 
                        </ul></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:eq` filter selector or `eq()` method to target the stylesheet you want:

```
$("link:eq(0)").attr("href",$(this).attr('rel'));
```

Specify the position to `eq` for the stylesheet you want to change the `href`. Off course you want to change the `href` of link stylesheet pointing to `red.css` and not `base.css`

---

Alternatively, you can apply an `id` to the link stylesheet you want to change the `href` ofL

```
<link id="someID"............/>
```

And later do:

```
$("link#someID").attr("href",$(this).attr('rel'));
```

Comment: WoW.. thats great!!.. I use your Alternatively answer and BINGO! works perfectly!.. ty dude!!!

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cssnewbie.com/simple-jquery-stylesheet-switcher/

tl;dr:

Somewhere in your HTML:

```
<link id="styles" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="red.css" /> in HTML
```

Somewhere in your jQuery:

```
$("#styles").attr("href","blue.css");
```