# how to change stylesheet when an image is clicked

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

JS newbie here

I want to have a kind of profile preview page where people can select a color (could be clicking on an image or could be a radio button) and that changes the background colors in certain divs in the preview page.

IE someone clicks on the button for red then the gradients in the background of the title bar, info boxes etc will turn to reds.

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: do you want to add stylesheets or modify css? are you looking for something like theme switcher widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'd be best off if you define specific stylesheets for each 'color' (read: style) you want to be available to the user. If the user clicks on something to make his color choice, you can change the stylesheet that is loaded. You probably will need a default.css or a main.css file that contains all positioning and default coloring stuff and for each color you have a separate css file like red.css that will load the colors for each element in your dom you want to be changed.

In simple Javascript this could look something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" id="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeStyle() {
        document.getElementById('stylesheet').href = 'style2.css';
    }
</script>
```

Of course, you can also include a library like jQuery to do this for you. Another option (non JS) is to do a POST when the user picks a color and change the stylesheet server side. But that will make the page refresh.

Comment: thanks for the answer. This looks exactly like what I want to do. Could you go into more detail about how to do it in jQuery tho. I've had a quick google and couldn't figure it out

Comment: First step is to include the library in the header of your page of course. Than add a script block and add: $(document).ready(function(){ $("#yourButton").click(function(){ $("#stylesheet").attr("href", "style2.css"); }) });

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#my-button').click(function(){
        $('.title-bar').css({'background' : 'red'});
    });
});
```

**Edit:**

I just hacked together a better (as in "programmatic") solution: http://jsfiddle.net/eNLs6/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.colorchanger').click(function(){
        $('#preview-div').css({'background' : $(this).val()});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class to the body and then use that in the stylesheet to create different themes.

JS:

```
$('#red').click(function() {
  document.body.className = 'red';
});
```

CSS:

```
body.red .title{background:url('red-gradient.png');}
body.red .color{color: red}
/* etc... */
```

You can of course put each theme in a separate CSS file, to make things easier to organize. But for performance reasons, I suggest you load all CSS at once and just  swap classes onclick, instead of a dynamic stylesheet loader .

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve that is to have different div classes for each color (theme in general) and change the css class of the div when button or image clicked :

```
$('#myRedButton').click(function(){$('#myDiv').attr('class','red')});
$('#myBlueButton').click(function(){$('#myDiv').attr('class','blue')});
```

And you will have a html looking like

```
<div id="myDiv">....the div that will have it's color changed </div>
<img src="..." id="myRedButton"/>
<img src="..." id="myBlueButton"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a base stylesheet (base.css) for general stuff and then secondary ones for each colour, eg red.css, blue.css

When a users clicks the red image, it loads the red.css stylesheet.

```
 $('#red').click(function() {

//load red.css
}
```

See this question on [how to change a secondary stylesheet with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762126/how-to-change-secondary-stylesheet-with-jquery) for more details.